# Change Color of Placeholder and Input Text and Border Of SEARCH

Tags: html, css

How can I change color of:

- Placeholder Text
- Input Text
- Border of Search

for example to blue?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
  
  <div class="container mt-3">
   <input class="form-control" id="myInput" type="text" placeholder="Search..">
  <div id="myDIV" class="mt-3">
  
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Change a HTML5 input's placeholder color with CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2610497/change-a-html5-inputs-placeholder-color-with-css)

Answer (score 0):

```html
<html>
<body>
<input type="text" placeholder="A red placeholder ">
<style>
::placeholder {
  color: red;
  opacity: 1; /* Firefox */
}

:-ms-input-placeholder { /* Internet Explorer 10-11 */
 color: red;
}

::-ms-input-placeholder { /* Microsoft Edge */
 color: red;
}
</style>
</body>
</html>
```